# Loop through database rows and create a single array

Tags: php

I have nooby PHP question that I can't figure out!

I loop through rows from my database:

```
    $data = array();

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryResult, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $data[] = $row;
    }
```

`$data` now contains an array within an array how can I have it so that its still just a single array?

Thanks all

Comment: an array of what? you may want to index data[] by the database id, right?

Comment: @galambalazs - its an array of rows from my database. I just want to have it as a single array so that I can process it later more easily. There is no real need but I wanted to know how to do this in case I need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It a more obvious way:

```
$data = array();

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryResult, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC){
  $data = array_merge( $data, array_values($row) );
}
```

Comment: should be ```while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryResult, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {```

Answer (score 4):

That's because each `$row` is an associative array. If you just want data to be an array of values from one column, specify that column:

```
$data = array();
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryResult, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $data[] = $row['column_name_you_want'];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Its going to be tedious to type all column names but I get the idea behind your method.

Comment: Hmmm... What's the point of that? In order to properly get all data, you'll need a 2D array anyways. You'll just be switching the order of the dimensions, but there is no way around having a multidimensional array.

Comment: (1) It's an associative array so you'll need to type every column name at least once somewhere to even access the data. (2) Depending on what you need to do with the data, rearranging it may be a waste of time. If you put the rows into `$data` you can always do something like this `$data[0]['column_name'] to access `column_name` in the first row, etc.

Comment: Actually, should it not be  `$data['column_name_you_want'] = $row['column_name_you_want'];` so that it stays as a single associative array, rather than an array that holds an associative array?

Comment: @Abs the point is you have rows and columns (hence a table): how would you condense both in a simple plain list?

Comment: If you did that, @Abs, then you would only ever have the data from the last row in your query.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you all values returned from all columns and rows as a single dimension array

```
$data = array();

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryResult, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $values = array_values($row);
    foreach($values as $value)
    {
        $data[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be like
```while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryResult, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but I was also looking for a solution to this. Came up with the following which works for me:

```
function mssql_query($conn, $query, array $bind = array()) {
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $bind);
    if( $stmt=== false ) {
        // do something with the error information
        // die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        return array();
    }
    sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
    $data = array();
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Which can be used directly in a foreach loop:

```
foreach(mssql_query($conn, $query) as $row) {
    echo $row['column'];
}
```

Or assigned to a variable for counting etc.

$conn is of course the connection (from PHP.net):

```
$serverName = "server.example.com"; // remember to append instance if applicable
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```